Dynamic update of input fields not saving input
I have some problems keeping the input when I add a new input. I want the default to be 2 input fields with some predetermined isin and number. Then I have added the option to add more input fields. However, when I write an isin and weight and pres "Add" it removes the newly written isin and weight. How can this be fixed?
The following can be used to test it
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

InputUI_dyn <- function(id) {
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      actionButton(NS(id, "add_btn"), "Add"),
      actionButton(NS(id, "remove_btn"), "Remove"),
      uiOutput(NS(id, "dynamic_isin_input"))
    )
  )
}

key_figuresServer <- function(id, isin_data, plotvars) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    #filtered_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)  # Reactive value to store filtered data
    
    inputs <- reactiveValues(input_list = list(
      tagList(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, textInput(NS(id, "isin_1"), label = "ISIN 1", value = "DK0009539116")),
          column(6, numericInput(NS(id, "weight_1"), label = "Weight 1", value = 100))
        )
      ),
      tagList(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, textInput(NS(id, "isin_2"), label = "ISIN 2", value = "DK0009527293")),
          column(6, numericInput(NS(id, "weight_2"), label = "Weight 2", value = -50))
        )
      )
    ),
    isin_values = list(),
    weight_values = list()
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
      new_input <- tagList(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, textInput(NS(id, paste0("isin_", length(inputs$input_list) + 1)), label = paste0("ISIN ", length(inputs$input_list) + 1), value = "")),
          column(6, numericInput(NS(id, paste0("weight_", length(inputs$input_list) + 1)), label = paste0("Weight ", length(inputs$input_list) + 1), value = 0))
        )
      )
      
      inputs$input_list <- c(inputs$input_list, new_input)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$remove_btn, {
      if (length(inputs$input_list) > 1) {
        inputs$input_list <- inputs$input_list[1:(length(inputs$input_list) - 1)]
      }
    })
    
    output$dynamic_isin_input <- renderUI({
      tagList(inputs$input_list)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      isin_values <- sapply(seq_along(inputs$input_list), function(i) {
        input_val <- input[[paste0("isin_", i)]]
        if (nchar(input_val) > 0) {
          input_val
        } else {
          NULL
        }
      })
      
      weight_values <- sapply(seq_along(inputs$input_list), function(i) {
        input_val <- input[[paste0("weight_", i)]]
        if (!is.null(input_val)) {
          as.numeric(input_val)
        } else {
          0
        }
      })
      
    })
    
  }
  )}


StrategyUI <- tabItem("TradingStrategy",
                      fluidPage(
                        h2("Strategy"),
                        hr(),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 12,
                                 InputUI_dyn("Strategy"))
                        )
                      )
)


StrategyServer <- function(id) {
  key_figuresServer("Strategy")
}




ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 200,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Relative Value", tabName = "Pricing", icon = icon("table"),
                              menuSubItem("Trading Strategy", tabName = "TradingStrategy")
                     )
                   )),
  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    ## Trading strategy
    StrategyUI
  )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  StrategyServer("Strategy")

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

